# i cannot call null data row in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Why I cannot call null data row when I use `IS NULL` in sqlite

```
select roomkeyID from roomkey where dateOfReturn is null;

CREATE TABLE ROOMKEY ( 
    roomkeyID VARCHAR(10) not null primary key,
    roomID VARCHAR(10) not null, 
    keyID VARCHAR(10) not null,
    dateOfIssue DATETIME,
    dateOfReturn DATETIME,
    FOREIGN KEY (roomID) REFERENCES ROOM(roomID),
    FOREIGN KEY (keyID ) REFERENCES KEY(keyID )
)

"RK000001","R106","K0003","12/17/2015"," "
"RK000090","R101","K0002","12/12/2015"," "
```

Comment: What is the output of `SELECT typeof(dateOfReturn), length(dateOfReturn) FROM roomkey WHERE roomkeyID = 'RK000001';`?

Answer (score 0):

From the example it seems that in the field `dateOfReturn` you do not have `NULL` values, but strings with a space inside. If this is true then you have to change your query to:

```
select roomkeyID from roomkey where dateOfReturn is null or dateOfReturn = ' '
```

Comment: TQ MR RENZO, but i using the answer that u show me it also cant work~

Comment: Please add to your question what happens when you do the query and what instead are you expecting. These things are not clear from your question. I cannot give a better answer otherwise.